# Can I implement singleton Pattern like this?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Wanted to explore new way to implement Singleton Pattern.Can this implementation be consider as a singleton Pattern ? If No Please give suggestions to improve the code.

```
 public interface Test {
        Singleton single = new Singleton();
        class Singleton {
            int i = 10;
            private Singleton(){}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not with an interface

Comment: Why would you ever do this?

Comment: @Kiran Bhagwat, you can very well use your approach to implement Singleton pattern. The `interface` fields are implicitly  `public static final`. They will be loaded only once. You have private constructor for the inner class and as  inner class of interface is static implicitly so it will be not be dependent upon an `instance` of outer class. Though your approach is not the best as other conventional approaches already exists but still your approach works. Check my answer below for more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can implement `Singleton` pattern this way. All the fields declared by an `Interface` are final and static. And you have a inner class defined inside an Interface with private constructor. Your way is different but seams  working. As the fields are static and final so they will be instantiated only once when the .class file for the interface is loaded.

Although the code works but still this is not the best way to implement Singleton. You can simply Create a normal Public class with private constructor. In this class you can define a `public static final` field of the type of the same class, initilize it with `new` keyword (you would be able to do so, even if the constructor is private because code inside a class can acess private entities). Your class is now `Singleton`. Another way to do this is via `Enum`.